# Modify signed .apk file for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

For some time I've been generating signed .apk files in Android Studio and then I was sending generated .apks to other people. Usually they were changing certificates of the apps.

Right now they can't do it, because every time I generate an apk in Android Studio it's locked for modifications and acts like read-only file. Is there a way to somehow disable that restriction in Android Studio or Gradle settings?

In Windows CMD the only attrib of generated and signed .apk file is an 'A'.

Comment: `Usually they were changing certificates of the apps` I'm not sure what you mean with this. The apk signature is created when building the project. `Right now they can't do it, because every time I generate an apk in Android Studio it's locked for modifications and acts like read-only file` apk is basically a zip file. You can change the `.apk` to `.zip` to test this. You will be able to see the files, but a lot  of it will be encrypted. There is ways to reverse engineer apk's, just Google it. `Is there a way to somehow disable that restriction in Android Studio or Gradle settings?` No

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.